# how to products api counts in shopify? (closed)

Tags: api, shopify, e-commerce, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

I Know how to count by this API

```
/admin/products/count.json ( total number of products)
```

but when I used this API then wrong count because when exports products then its more than count
Example

```
Response : {count:1000}
Exports products total: 1440
```

Comment: Need more code information to make a comment

Comment: @OnkarSingh  I have store I want to know about how many products in my store
1. Exports products from Shopify 
2. use products API